# Can concret board be used as flooring board on an upper floor?

Tags: concrete, cement-board

Does concrete board have the strength to be like flooring board spanning on joist or rafters as a second floor. That is not setting on solid ground. I think it can’t hold constant walking weight and furniture.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Ordinary concrete (cementitous) boards are not meant to be subfloor. (See below for an exception.) For subfloor, you need a wood product of some description.

Hat tip to @ThreePhaseEel for mention of USG cement flooring product. From the manufacturer’s info, these are used in commercial settings and weigh 175 pounds per sheet.

Comment: There *are* cemetitious subfloor boards, but they are *thick* beasts, thicker than the OSB they replace and a fair bit heavier as well: https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en/products/roofing-building-envelope/concrete-subfloor-panels/structo-crete-structural-panels.html

Comment: Well, not *that* much thicker—OSB subfloor is min 23/32", and those Structo-crete panels are only 3/4".  Heavier is obvious. :)